# Why does g++ on Windows statically link the standard library by default?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

I have a C++ program which makes use of some C++ standard libraries such as iostream, vector, sstream and so on, and is only about 120 lines of code. By building it on Debian I get a 25KB executable, while when I build it on Windows 11 (both of them with just "g++ main.cpp") I normally get a 3026KB .exe. If instead I type "--shared-libstdc++" alongside g++ on Windows, I get a smaller .exe, merely 290KB.

My question is, why does compiling and linking in a Linux environment automatically do this while on Windows I have to specify it? Is there a drawback to dynamically linking the standard C++ library on Windows that G++ is aware of?

On Windows, I have: gcc version 10.3.0 (tdm64-1)

On Debian, I have: gcc version 11.3.0 (Debian 11.3.0-3)

Comment: https://github.com/jmeubank/tdm-distrib/blob/master/tdm32/core/README-gcc-tdm.md : "TDM-GCC builds DLLs and EXEs with statically-linked libgcc and libstdc++, that rely on a shared memory region to propagate exceptions. [...]"

Comment: @Mat Thanks, I didn't know that TDM-GCC specifically implemented it like this, but I can't find the reason behind it.